# Does marshaling a marshaled interface give me a marshaller to the proxy or the original interface?

Tags: windows, com, marshalling, out-of-process

Here is a concrete example:

I create a [IWeBrowser2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752127) interface by calling `wb.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, 0, CLSCTX_SERVER);`. This gives me a marshaled interface from my process into whichever of the running iexplore.exe processes happens to contain this browser tab in my *thread A*.

Now I use the [IGlobalInterfaceTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678517) to get a cookie for this interface, pass it to my *thread B* and request the marshaled interface from there.

***Question:*** Do I get a proxy to the proxy in my thread A or directly to the instance in the IE process?

It seems sensible to me that I will get a direct proxy to the instance with its own reference to it, 
 **however**:

If I end my thread A, the cookie I created there becomes invalid and I can't retrieve (and close) the interface pointers to the web browsers I created any more. This does not make sense unless there is a thunk in that thread that is destroyed when the thread quits.

*Edit:* Oh, both threads are STA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally had some time to figure out what is happening, so I wrote a short test to see what is going on.

```
// MarshalTest.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

enum { WM_THEREYOUGO = WM_USER+1, WM_THANKYOU, WM_YOURWELCOME };

DWORD WINAPI TheOtherThread(DWORD * main_thread_id)
{
    MSG msg = { 0 };
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

    {
        // create web browser
        CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> wb;
        hr = wb.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetExplorer, 0, CLSCTX_SERVER);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr) && wb);

        // navigate
        hr = wb->Navigate2(&CComVariant(_T("stackoverflow.com")), &CComVariant(0), &CComVariant(_T("")), &CComVariant(), &CComVariant());
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        hr = wb->put_Visible(VARIANT_TRUE);
        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

        // Marshal
        DWORD the_cookie = 0;
        {
            CComPtr<IGlobalInterfaceTable> com_broker;
            hr = com_broker.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
            hr = com_broker->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(wb, __uuidof(IWebBrowser2), &the_cookie);
        }

        // notify main thread
        PostThreadMessage(*main_thread_id, WM_THEREYOUGO, the_cookie, NULL);

        // message loop
        while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
            if(msg.hwnd == NULL) {
                // thread message
                switch(msg.message) {
                    case WM_THANKYOU:
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }

    CoUninitialize();

    PostThreadMessage(*main_thread_id, WM_YOURWELCOME, 0, NULL);
    return msg.wParam;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MSG msg = {0};
    DWORD main_thread_id = GetCurrentThreadId();

    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED);
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
    {
        DWORD ThreadId = 0;
        HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)TheOtherThread, &main_thread_id, 0, &ThreadId);

        DWORD the_cookie = 0;

        CComPtr<IWebBrowser2> wb, wb2;

        while(GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
            if(msg.hwnd == NULL) {
                // thread message
                switch(msg.message) {
                    case WM_THEREYOUGO:
                        // we got the cookie.
                        the_cookie = msg.wParam;

                        // get the browser. This should work.
                        {
                            CComPtr<IGlobalInterfaceTable> com_broker;
                            hr = com_broker.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable);
                            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
                            hr = com_broker->GetInterfaceFromGlobal(the_cookie, __uuidof(IWebBrowser2), (void**)&wb);
                            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr) && wb);
                        }

                        // do something with it.
                        hr = wb->put_FullScreen(VARIANT_TRUE);
                        assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));

                        // signal the other thread.
                        PostThreadMessage(ThreadId, WM_THANKYOU, 0, NULL);
                        break;

                    case WM_YOURWELCOME:
                        // the other thread has ended.
                        PostQuitMessage(0);
                        break;
                }
            } else {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        // the other thread has ended. Try getting the interface again.
        {
            CComPtr<IGlobalInterfaceTable> com_broker;
            hr = com_broker.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
            hr = com_broker->GetInterfaceFromGlobal(the_cookie, __uuidof(IWebBrowser2), (void**)&wb2);
            //assert(SUCCEEDED(hr) && wb2); // this fails, hr == E_INVALIDARG.

            // clean up, will not be executed.
            if(SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
                hr = com_broker->RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal(the_cookie);
            }
        }

        // try using it
        if(wb2) {
            hr = wb2->put_FullScreen(VARIANT_FALSE);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        } else if(wb) {
            // this succeeds
            hr = wb->put_FullScreen(VARIANT_FALSE);
            assert(SUCCEEDED(hr));
        }

        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
    return msg.wParam;
}
```

---

The bottom line is this:

- Ending the thread that registered the interface invalidates the cookie.
- The already marshaled interface stays valid. (In this case, that is.)

This means that I get a proxy to the IE process instead of to the other thread's object.

Answer (score 1):

You already got a proxy on thread A since you asked for an out-of-process server.  What happens next depends on the kind of apartment that thread A lives in, the argument to CoInitializeEx().  If it is MTA you will definitely get the same proxy in thread B, assuming it is MTA as well.  The added reference count should keep it alive if Thread A exits.  If it is STA then I'm not 100% sure but think you ought to get a new one.  Easy to test btw, just use the one from thread A and you'll get RPC_E_WRONGTHREAD if a new one would have to be created.

I don't have a great explanation for why the thread A exit kills the proxy for thread B.  Unless you call IGlobalInterfaceTable::RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal().  Which you'd normally do.

Comment: Both threads are STA. Also, I don't call RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal. GetInterfaceFromGlobal just returns E_INVALIDARG when I call it after thread A ended.

Comment: Very unusual.  Where are you calling RevokeInterfaceFromGlobal?

Comment: I have a reference counted object that handles the cookie. When all references are gone, it gets revoked. The cookies are kept in a pool and released at exit.

Comment: Sounds okayish but dangerous.  What references are you actually counting?  Do you count up for each GetInterfaceFromGlobal and down when that returned pointer gets counted down to zero by Release() calls?  Sounds very hard to do, you can't override the Release method easily.  I smell a problem, set a break on the Revoke call.

Comment: No, the cookie holder object itself is guarded by a smart pointer. When it gets deleted the cookie is revoked. The cookie holder is also the class that requests the interface.